# How do I get the actual string from CDATA in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Say I have a node tree:

```
<data>
    <current-query-string><![CDATA[location=burnley]]></current-query-string>
</data>
```

How would I get the text only from inside the CDATA tags?

It's been a very long time since I wrote xslt at this level, and I cannot remember how to do it. I understand that CDATA is plain text, and how it all works, just not how to extract the actual string only.

Simply using:

```
<a href="blah.com/?{/data/current-query-string}">link</a>
```

is giving me:

```
<a href="blah.com/?<![CDATA[location=burnley]]>">link</a>
```

I expect that result, I need to see the result:

```
<a href="blah.com/?location=burnley">link</a>
```

How do I use the value as plain text?

Comment: CDATA is transparent. You don't have to worry about it. It just works. The test you see is the correct data inside the CDATA.

Comment: The result you claim is not the result obtained: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCRK

Comment: The processor you are using, if it returns `<![CDATA[location=burnley]]>` rather than `location=burnley`, has a nasty bug.

Comment: Could it be your actual XML has some mis-applied escaping, and actually looks something like `<current-query-string>&lt;![CDATA[location=burnley]]&gt;</current-query-string>`?

Comment: Tim C, you are right, there is a slight bug in the implementation I am using that has escaped the CDATA.